# PHP json_encode switching array to object in a particular server... why?

Tags: php, json

I have a library that read a directory and join a lot of information in a single object, so I can get it by JSON and work on it with JavaScript. I have a php that calls the lib for me and returns the JSON, simple as this:

```
echo('&vars_ini=OK&dados='.json_encode($Lista).'&vars_fim=');
```

After get the value of "dados", this is what I got:

```
{"erro":"OK","Lista":[{"nome":"a-process.gif","base":"a-process","ext":"gif","bytes":93117,"datac":"07\/04\/2016 13:46","datam":"31\/05\/2017 20:06","timestampc":1460047579,"timestampm":1496272006}, ... etc. there is also other lists as subdirectories.
```

But in this particular server, I am getting this:

```
{"erro":"OK","Lista":{"22":{"nome":"a-process.gif","base":"a-process","ext":"gif","bytes":93117,"datac":"03\/08\/2016 18:33","datam":"03\/08\/2016 18:26","timestampc":1470249183,"timestampm":1470248785},"43":{"nome":"g-agenda.gif","base":"g-agenda","ext":"gif","bytes":1454,"datac":"03\/08\/2016 18:33","datam":"03\/08\/2016 18:26","timestampc":1470249183,"timestampm":1470248786}, ... etc.
```

Instead of "Lista" be rendered with "[", there is a "{". My testing server is running php 5.6.10 and this server is 5.6.27. I don't think is a version problem (really?) but maybe some directive is telling to work like this.

The simple solution is to convert those objects to array, no big deal, but I am trying to understand why this is happening and to optimize my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start your array at `0` and increment contiguously to get a JSON array.  Failing that, use `array_values()` to re-index the PHP array before `json_encode()`.

In your first example the array index starts at `0` so `json_encode()` treats it as an array.  In the second the array index starts at `22` so it is treated as an object. The indexes also need to be contiguous to generate an array. Somehow you generate or get different indexes in each instance (maybe sorting or other function that defines or moves the indexes).

This shows contiguous indexes starting at `0`:

```
$v = range(1,5);
print_r($v);
echo json_encode($v);
```

Yields an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
)
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

While starting at `1`:

```
$k = range(1,5);
$z = array_combine($k, $v);    
print_r($z);
echo json_encode($z);
```

Yields an object:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 5
)
{"1":1,"2":2,"3":3,"4":4,"5":5}
```

Starting at `0` with non-contiguous indexes:

```
$z = array(0, 2=>2, 3=>3, 5=>5);
print_r($z);
echo json_encode($z);
```

Yields an object:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [5] => 5
)
{"0":0,"2":2,"3":3,"5":5}
```

Comment: Interesting. Well, the library works by creating an empty array ($this->Lista = array();) than the files, one by one, using readdir and simple pushing using $this->Lista[] = $ldArq;. Than, there is some sort operations (by date, name, etc) that may occur or not. I will try to reenumerate the array, see if I will have the contiguous indexes...

Comment: Yes! By adding $this->Lista = array_values($this->Lista); the list is now seen as simple sequential array []. Is still a mystery why the same code worked differently in other environment trying to do the same task... I am missing something... But this simple line will prevent further problems. I suggest you to add this solution in your answer so I can flag it.

Comment: Added at the bottom.  Thought it would be easier to find out why the indexes were the way they were :)